# Can you create a unique variable name by concatenating two other variables?

Tags: java, class, object

I am trying to make a method that will create a new unique object based on another class that I have have in the same project. I know that the last line wont compile, but is there a way to accomplish the same goal?

Ideally if the fName=John and lName=Smith, then the new "Employee" object created on the last line would be called "JohnSmith" but the goal is just to create a unique instance of the object every time that the method is called

```
public static void createEmployee(int number){

   Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.printf("Enter first name for employee %s: ",number);
   String fName=input.next();
   System.out.printf("Enter last name for employee %s: ",number);
   String lName=input.next();
   Employee fName+lName= new Employee(fName,lName);
   }
```

I am fairly new to Java, and object oriented programming in general so if I am going about this wrong I am open to going about it a different way.

Comment: Think in terms of an array or java.util.Map rather than renaming variables.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan: Your comment seems to be the best answer so far. All other answers are nice too, but something really simple, with basic arrays, would be most appropriate in this case.

Comment: This is a good solution, and I will probably implement an array in the full version, but right now I am just building a test app where I only need to create two instances.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you're describing isn't possible.

As a conceptual exercise, your variables should describe the kind of data they're holding. It may sound pretty plain, but `employee` would be a better name for that variable than `JohnSmith` or `SteveJobs` or any other first + last name combination.

If you're intending to create a new instance of an `Employee` every time, you should return the Employee instance from the method instead of declaring it `void`.  Then you can use it however you like wherever you call it.

```
public static Employee createEmployee(int number){

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.printf("Enter full name of employee %d, separated by spaces: ", number);
   String fName = input.next();
   String lName = input.next();
   return new Employee(fName, lName);
}
```

Comment: This was actually a simple solution to what I was trying to do in this case. I don't know why I didn't think to use a return in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. But remember, many "JohnSmith" exist - you would run into homonyms easily.

If these aren't a problem, you could use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to bind a key (The String made with Surname + Name) to a value (your employee).

Good luck and welcome to StackOverflow!

**UPDATE**

If homonyms **are** a problem, you will need to use unique IDs; they assure you that you have no overlaps. You could build an ID in the Employee itself, and put them in a `List`, or you can put them in an `Array` - the ID will then be their position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't combine a variable like that, but you could say something like

```
// Employee fName+lName= new Employee(fName,lName);
Employee employee = new Employee(fName, lName);
```

And if `Employee` overrides `toString()` then

```
System.out.println(employee);
```

should give you the output you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I second the hashmap. Having a human readable variable name dynamically created is overly complicated. Using a hashmap you can reference the object with a string

```
HashMap<String, Employee> employees = new HashMap<String, Employee>();

employees.put(fName + lName, new Employee(fName, lName));
```

To get the employ obj

```
employees.get(fName + lName);
```

Comment: You're going to have a bad time if you have two people with the same names with this approach.

Comment: You could upvote an answer you second. :-P @Makoto, that much is clear; but if homonyms aren't an issue for some reason, this works well. One should use unique IDs.

Comment: True but those were the "ideal" parameters he specified in his question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know anything about HashMaps before and now that I have looked into some of the things that you can do with them, I will definitely be using them in future projects.  The simplest solution in this case was Makoto's suggestion of having a return value create the variable.  Again I appreciate help!